# C# data type equivalent to VBA exponential form

Tags: c#, .net, vba, excel

I have an old VBA application that has generates values like 1.123456789123456789123456789E-28. When I googled to find the equivalent data type in C#, I found this article in SO  [Difference between decimal, float and double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net).  As per what this post suggests, decimal data type has the largest size in C#. So I used decimal data type but I found that decimal seems to be limited in representing large values that VBA represents in exponential form. So I googled again and found this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae55hdtk.aspx. As stated in this article,

> Nonintegral number values can be expressed as mmmEeee, in which mmm is
>   the mantissa (the significant digits) and eee is the exponent (a power
>   of 10). The highest positive values of the nonintegral types are
>   7.9228162514264337593543950335E+28 for Decimal, 3.4028235E+38 for Single, and 1.79769313486231570E+308 for Double.

This means Double data type has the largest range of values. So now I am confused between decimal and double.

Then I did a little experiment with code like below

```
    double dbl = 1.123456789123456789123456789E-28;
    decimal dcl = 1.123456789123456789123456789E-28M;
    MessageBox.Show(dbl.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(dcl.ToString());
```

The dbl prints the value as it is 1.123456789123456789123456789E-28 while the dcl value changes to 0.0000000000000000000000000001;
Can someone explain what is happening here ? What is the equivalent data type in C# to represent large exponential values like in VBA with same precision?

Comment: I think if you read that first article further, you will understand the differences and when to use them. I think you may have misunderstood that first link you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the C# language specification: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691085%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

> - A real literal suffixed by F or f is of type float. For example, the literals 1f, 1.5f, 1e10f, and 123.456F are all of type float.
> - A real literal suffixed by D or d is of type double. For example, the literals 1d, 1.5d, 1e10d, and 123.456D are all of type double.
> - A real literal suffixed by M or m is of type decimal. For example, the literals 1m, 1.5m, 1e10m, and 123.456M are all of type decimal.
>     This literal is converted to a decimal value by taking the exact
>     value, and, if necessary, rounding to the nearest representable value
>     using banker's rounding (Section 4.1.7). Any scale apparent in the
>     literal is preserved unless the value is rounded or the value is zero
>     (in which latter case the sign and scale will be 0). Hence, the
>     literal 2.900m will be parsed to form the decimal with sign 0,
>     coefficient 2900, and scale 3.

Looking at the third bullet point, you can see the phrase "...*This literal is converted to a decimal value by taking the exact value...*". The value you are getting (`0.0000000000000000000000000001`) is the converted result of the input literal (`1.123456789123456789123456789E-28M`) that you started with. Of course, with the value rounded as per the second part of the third bullet-point regarding the conversion "*...if necessary, rounding to the nearest representable value using banker's rounding...*".

This is true for `decimal`, but for `float` or `double` the exponential notation can be preserved by the data type itself, so no conversion/rounding is necessary.

**Addition:**

To expand further on the above, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx

This is the definition for the `decimal` data type. As noted there: the range of `decimal` is `(-7.9 x 1028 to 7.9 x 1028) / (100 to 28)` or `28 to 29 significant digits`. Your literal, `1.123456789123456789123456789E-28M` is beyond that limit, so when it is converted, everything to the right of the 1 is rounded as per the rules above.

**Solution(?):**

If you need a larger precision than `decimal` can provide, you may want to look into implementing your own class, which is definitely doable. Consider searching for C# implementations of `BigDecimal` for ideas.

One implementation I found on a quick google: https://gist.github.com/nberardi/2667136

I cannot speak to its correctness, but it could at least be a starting point for you.

Answer (score 1):

`float` and `double` are floating point numbers. That means that they are holding number and exponential coefficient separatly, where `double` is double size of `float`. `double` is not recommended to use in cases when precision is important, for example prices.
`decimal` is holding numbers in "decimal" form, with fixed point. It's more precise, especially with decimal calculations.
It seems that `double` is more likely to be what you're looking for.